# Styled theme actionBarCompat with AppCompat v7

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I have  a styled theme in `values/styles.xml` like this, project compiled and targetting Android 21:

```
    <style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#99ba64</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#558B2F</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#76FF03</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar.TabView</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ListView.DropDown</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.PopupMenu</item>
</style>
```

action bar works with styled background color on all devices, but some colors such as for `popupmenu` or `navspinner` are missed. It seems as `android:popupMenuStyle`  or  `android:actionDropDownStyle`  are ignored. Why?  Thanks.

Comment: I had encountered a similar problem. Try to also define popMenuStyle alongside android:popupMenuStyle (do the same with that actionDropDownStyle). Hope this'll fix it.

Comment: I edited my code: the issue is only when styling from `.DarkActionBar` theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targetting API 21,  then you can't use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` - it doesn't exist.

Read this [Chris Banes blog post](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) about AppCompat v21.

Comment: Yes, but if I'm not mistaken, on all platforms the theme `AppCompat` inherits from `Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat` in which there are attributes `popupMenuStyle` and `actionDropDownStyle`. I can not understand how and why they are ignored if i style `.DarkActionBar`. Thanks.